# JavaScript replace regex :(

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace invalid characters when entering a phone number

The rules i want are below.

- The first character can be "+"
- The remaining characters have to be digits 0-9

This is what I have already

```
phoneNumber.getValue().replace(/[^0-9,+]+/g, "");
```

this works, kind of but not fully

however I can have a "+" anywhere in the string 
I want to remove this if it is not the first character does anyone now how to-do this

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a slightly smarter regex.

```
phoneNumber.getValue().replace(/.*(?=\+)|[^0-9]/g,'')
```

This regex sort of abuses the fact that alternation in replacements work from left to right. Because the `+` has sort of been "covered" by the lookahead in the first alternation, it is effectively immune to being deleted by the `[^0-9]` part.

Comment: do you know how i would need to escape this to work correctly

Comment: sorry my mistake, i had an error else where, if i enter +56465454+884 it will remove everything before the second plus. ideally i want it to just remove that second plus

Comment: @AndrewJackson That would take a bit more complex code ;) Since I don't know where you are using this code, I don't really have anything to work with.

Comment: its for Dynamics CRM, i want to be able to validate the phone number entered but first i just want to make sure that i'm only dealing with numbers and a an optional plus at the front for the country code, Hope this makes sense, also thanks for you help so far too

Comment: If you can use `match` instead of `replace`, try `.match(/^\+?[0-9]+$/)`

Comment: `/.*(?=\+)|[^0-9]/g` does not work. Given the string: `"+123+"` this replace pattern returns: `"+"`.

Comment: @ridgerunner The result is a string that begins with an optional `+` followed by some (in this case zero) digits. The fact that the wrong `+` was treated as the first character is irrelevant, but could be solved by doing `.*?` instead of just `.*`

Comment: No, when: `/.*?(?=\+)|[^0-9]/g` is applied to the target string: `"+123+"`, the result is: `"++"` - still not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you *don't* want to include commas, (i.e. the result should be only decimal digits preceded by an optional `+`), then this will do it:

```js
phoneNumber.getValue().replace(/(^\+)|\D+/g, '$1');
```

Notes:

- Makes use of the `\D` *non-decimal digit* character class shorthand. (i.e. `\D` is the same as: `[^0-9]`.)
- Makes use of the fact that when a capturing group does not participate in the match,  it can still be referenced in the replacement string - (it is replaced with the empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Another one would be

```
phoneNumber.getValue().replace(/[^\+0-9]/g, '')
```

When using "**+1234abc+5678**" as value this results in "**+1234+5678**"
Whereas the regex of Niet the Dark Absol results in "**+5678**"

Probably you have to combine that using substring to remove the second plus.
That would be pretty easy.